# Can't write to table using TYPO3 v7 forms

Tags: database, forms, typo3

I've tried installing the "Form PostProcessor for DB Inserts" extension for TYPO3 to allow forms to post data to a table.

The test example in the documentation works well and allows a form to add a new user to the fe_users table.
However, if I create a new table, that copies the structure of fe_users, when I try to write to it using the form builder, I get a non-specific error.

Could I be having permission issues with writing to certain tables?
using: TYPO3 v7.6.18 and ext_form: 7.6.0

Comment: Please tell us the error message. It should be in your log at least!

Comment: I tuned on error logging in Typo and all i get is: Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20170522104040b547980c

Comment: Then you need to disable to content object exception handler with ``config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0``.